# how can i remove 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    document.getElementById('getMessage').onclick=function(){
        req=new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST",'http://114.143.206.69:803/StandardForwardStagingService.svc/GetAWBNumberGeneratedSeries',false);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req.setRequestHeader('XBKey','******');
        req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type');
        req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','XBKey');
        req.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200){
                document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0].innerHTML=req.responseText;
            }
        };
        var obj = {"BusinessUnit" : "ECOM","ServiceType" : "FORWARD","BatchID" : "Jopu7E9821"};
        req.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
    };
});
</script>
```

When I click on the button I get the following "access control allow header" error message:

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is a _response_ header, so that you are trying to set it as a _request_ header makes no sense at all. Go read up on how CORS works if you want to use it.

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact that it is absolute nonsense one single bit.

Comment: @CBroe Okay, I will read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) on your google chrome browser.And enable it. Hope it will fix your problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

CORS is configured server-side. If you have control over

http://114.143.206.69:803/StandardForwardStagingService.svc/GetAWBNumberGeneratedSeries

You'll need to set the header to allow Cross Origin Requests. How this is done, is dependent on the language of the server side code.

For example, if it's running PHP, you can allow CORS in any PHP file with the following

```
<?php
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```